# Installing Pipenv on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, blockchain, pipenv, pipenv-install

I am a complete beginner and just finished my first Python course on mimo.

Now I would like to try myself on a project to create a blockchain in python.
https://medium.com/@vanflymen/learn-blockchains-by-building-one-117428612f46

For this project I need to install pipenv but am struggeling to install it.

Neither cmd or pycharm lets me follow through the steps as presented under this link:

https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/

I assume that I need to connect python with windows via the environment variable but struggeling to do that.

Anaconda is also installed on my computer.

Could you guys please help me with this topic?

cheers
Basti